Excel Ribbon: Disable all custom tabs if worksheet is protected
If a worksheet is protected, most of the built-in buttons are greyed out.
How do you do this with a custom ribbon?
How do you say: If the worksheet is protected, disable all custom tabs / all buttons in custom tabs and turn them back on, if the sheet is unprotected?
Framework XML, Standard Module, ThisWorkbook:
' -- XML

<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui"
 onLoad="LoadRibbon">
  <ribbon>
    <tabs>
      <tab id="Tabv3.1" label="TOOLS" insertAfterMso="TabHome">                  
       ' groups/buttons 
      </tab>
    </tabs>
  </ribbon>
</customUI>


' -- Standard Module

Option Explicit
Public RibUI As IRibbonUI

Sub LoadRibbon(Ribbon As IRibbonUI)
Set RibUI = Ribbon
    RibUI.InvalidateControl "xy"
End Sub

' =========
' Callbacks
' =========


' -- ThisWorkbook

Private Sub Workbook_SheetActivate(ByVal Sh As Object)
    RibUI.InvalidateControl "xy"
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_SheetSelectionChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    RibUI.InvalidateControl "xy"
End Sub

Framework Ribbon with 2 Tabs, "Tools" and "Macros":
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui" 
 onLoad="LoadRibbon">   
  <ribbon>  
    <tabs>  
      <tab id="ToolsV1.0.0" label="Tools" insertAfterMso="Developer">   
       ' built-in controls + a couple of macro buttons
      </tab>
      <tab id="MacrosV4.0.0" label="Macros" insertAfterMso="ToolsV1.0.0">
       ' macro buttons      
      </tab>               
    </tabs> 
  </ribbon> 
</customUI> 


Theoretically, it can be done, but it depends on some issues, respectively: 1. Is the workbook containing the above code (and has XML to create the custom Ribbon Tab) an add-in? If not, do you want the above described behavior only for the respective workbook, or not? In all cases, solution will be different 2. Why do you ask about "all custom tabs", since in the XML you show only a tab ("TOOLS") is created? Are there other tabs created by other workbooks/add-ins? Even in such a case it could be done, but solution would be much more complicated.

Yes, the workbook has an XML with onLoad to build the ribbon, it's not an add-in. The above code is only an example, the real ribbon has two custom Tabs. 1. "Tools": mostly built-in controls plus some macro buttons 2. "Macros": macro buttons. If possible, I'd like to have the decribed behaviour for any workbook containing the ribbon.

Basically, it is needed to add getEnabled on controls you want to conditionally Enable - Disable (in XML), then Invalidate the respective controls. I will try showing a small such example:

The suggested solution refers the next XML, inserting two Tabs, each of them containing a control.
After Edit I added <commands> for standard "SheetProtect" idMso, hooking its OnAction event:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<customUI onLoad="RibbonLoaded_Addin" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui"> 
  <commands>
      <command idMso="SheetProtect" onAction="mySheetProtect" />
  </commands>
  <ribbon> 
    <tabs> 
      <tab id="ToolsV1.0.0" label="TOOLS"  insertAfterMso="Developer"> 
        <group id="GroupDemo" label="Test group1"> 
           <dropDown id="TestDrD"  
                    label = "Test dropDown:"
                    getEnabled="Test_getEnabled"/>
                     
        </group>        
    </tab>
    <tab id="MacrosV4.0.0" label="Macros" insertAfterMso="ToolsV1.0.0">  
        <group id="GroupDemo2" label="Test group2"        
            imageMso="AddInManager">    
             <checkBox id="myCheckbox" 
                     getEnabled="Chk_getEnabled" /> 
        </group>       
      </tab> 
    </tabs> 
  </ribbon> 
</customUI> 


In a standard module you need to add the next declarations (on top of it, in the declarations area) and API functions. The API functions (not required) are a bonus, to refresh MyRibbon object when it is lost (in case of VBA errors):

Option Explicit

'To memorize the Ribbon object! ___________
#If VBA7 Then
        Private Declare PtrSafe Sub CopyMemory Lib "kernel32" Alias "RtlMoveMemory" (Destination As Any, Source As Any, ByVal length As LongPtr)
#Else
        Private Declare Sub CopyMemory Lib "kernel32" Alias "RtlMoveMemory" (Destination As Any, Source As Any, ByVal Length As Long)
#End If
'_________________________________________


Public myRibbon As IRibbonUI
Const strRib As String = "\MyRibbX" 'where to save the pointer...

Public boolEnableChk As Boolean, boolDrD As Boolean 'to Disable/Enable

Copy also the next procedures in that standard module:
a. To run on Ribbon is loaded (memorize the Ribbon pointer and initially set as Enabled the necessary controls):
Sub RibbonLoaded_Addin(ribbon As IRibbonUI)
    Dim Path As String: Path = Environ("temp") & strRib
    Dim File As Integer: File = FreeFile
    Open Path For Output As #File
        Print #File, ObjPtr(ribbon) 'memorize IRibbonUI pointer
    Close #File

   Set myRibbon = ribbon
   
   boolEnableChk = True: boolDrD = True 'to initialy enable controls
   myRibbon.InvalidateControl "myCheckbox" 'to update it
   myRibbon.InvalidateControl "TestDrD"
End Sub

b. The sub able to recuperate the lost Ribbon object:
Sub getRibbon() 'reSet myRibbon if it was lost (it's Nothing):
    Dim Path As String: Path = Environ("temp") & strRib
    Dim File As Integer: File = FreeFile
    Dim ribValue As String
    
    If myRibbon Is Nothing Then
        Open Path For Input As #File
            Input #File, ribValue
        Close #File
        
        #If VBA7 Then
            CopyMemory myRibbon, CLngPtr(ribValue), 8 'place in memory IRibbonUI object from its memorized pointer '64 bit
        #Else
            CopyMemory myRibbon, CLng(ribValue), 4    'place in memory IRibbonUI object from its memorized pointer
        #End If
    End If
End Sub

c. The two necessary getEnabled events:
Sub Chk_getEnabled(control As IRibbonControl, ByRef enabled)
  enabled = boolEnableChk
End Sub

Sub Test_getEnabled(control As IRibbonControl, ByRef enabled)
  enabled = boolDrD
End Sub

d. Two (only) testing subs to see how the Ribbon controls are alternatively changed when play with them?
Sub testMakeEn_Dis_ChkBox() 'pressing alternatively it will enable/disable the check box
  boolEnableChk = Not boolEnableChk
  
  If myRibbon Is Nothing Then getRibbon
  myRibbon.InvalidateControl ("myCheckbox")
End Sub

Sub testMakeEn_Dis_DropD() 'pressing alternatively it will enable/disable the DropDown
  boolDrD = Not boolDrD
  
  If myRibbon Is Nothing Then getRibbon
  myRibbon.InvalidateControl ("TestDrD")
End Sub

e. And the next Sub able to replace the above testing ones, having a parameters to define the control name to be Enabled\Disabled:
Sub Invalidate_Control(controlName As String) 'to be used externaly
  If myRibbon Is Nothing Then getRibbon
  myRibbon.InvalidateControl controlName
End Sub


Please, copy the next code in ThisWorkbook code module. Workbook_SheetActivate event is triggered when you activate different sheets and according to its evaluation related to protections Enables or Disables the necessary controls:

Option Explicit

Private Sub Workbook_SheetActivate(ByVal sh As Object)
  If sh.ProtectContents Then
    boolEnableChk = False
    'boolDrD = False 'uncomment to also use it
  Else
    boolEnableChk = True
    'boolDrD = True 'uncomment to also use it
  End If
  Invalidate_Control "myCheckbox"
  'Invalidate_Control "TestDrD" 'uncomment to also use it
End Sub

Please, send some feedback after testing it. In a following comment I will also send a tested workbook (using a transfer site, it can be downloaded in a limited period of time)...
Edit:
To trigger the "Protect Sheet" button click you should add it in the XML part (between <commands> - </commands>), see above and in VBA you need to also copy the next Sub, able to trigger/hook button 'OnAction` event and use it:
Sub mySheetProtect(ByVal control As IRibbonControl, ByRef cancelDefault)
  Dim ShPr As CommandBarButton
  Set ShPr = Application.CommandBars.FindControl(msoControlButton, ID:=893) 'legacy way of finding the control caption...
                                                                            'control getText is not exposed...
  If ShPr.Caption = "&Protect Sheet..." Then
    boolEnableChk = False
    boolDrD = False
  Else
    boolEnableChk = True
    boolDrD = True
  End If
  Invalidate_Control "TestDrD": Invalidate_Control "myCheckbox"

  cancelDefault = False 'without it protect/unprotect is cancelled...
End Sub

Please, send some feedback after testing it.

@user23636411 Please, download from here a workbook where I played to test the above solution. If something not clear, do not hesitate to ask for clarifications...

FaneDuru: Just tested your workbook in Win10/Excel2019 and in OSX 10.11.6/Excel2016. Basically it works: if you open the workbook and the sheet is protected, both controls are greyed out. But: the controls don't refresh instantly like the built-ins, when clicking on "Protect/Unprotect Sheet". Example checkbox: Sheet1 is protected. I click "Unprotect Sheet". The checkbox stays disabled. But if I jump to Sheet2 and back to Sheet1, now the checkbox is enabled. I uncommented the three lines in Workbook_SheetActivate. What am I missing? Thx!

@user23636411 Nope, you are not missing anything...  So was designed the above solution. I understood that the code needs to disable the control IF the worksheet is protected. If I would understand When the sheet is protected I wouldn't do anything. Excel does not expose any event able to trigger the protection change. But I think I will be able to deal with this aspect, too. I mean, in the past I was able o hook the command bar control click event. Now, I heard about the possibility of such a control repurposing. I will try that but not now, I am  not at home...

@user23636411 But you can ask another question mentioning that the requirement is also for the moment when the protection is done and maybe somebody else will solve the problem. If not, I will try solving it when I will be at home. I am almost sure I will handle it...

@user23636411 Please, test the solution I posted after Edit and read carefully how you also have to adapt the XML Code. You can also download from here the adapted workbook.

FaneDuru: With the updates, the controls now react instantly and change their state, when clicking Protect/Unprotect Sheet. All custom buttons now behave like the built-in buttons. Everything works perfectly in Win10/Excel2019 as well as in OSX10.11.6/Excel2016. +1!

@user23636411 Do not look only to effect... Try understanding and learning. This new event does what you recently clarified and describe now. But the previous one does what is to be done when you move between the sheets. Without the previous event code, it will consider all sheets being protected or not protected according to this last event action, in terms of your custom controls behavior.

FaneDuru: Yes. If I got it right, the first event is Workbook_SheetActivate. This takes care of the controls reacting to a sheet change. If a sheet is protected, the controls are disabled and vice versa. The second event, the new one is mySheetProtect, which will change the state of the controls, if you click on the button Protect/Unprotect Sheet. For this, you repurposed the getText-control. To make both events work together, you have to uncomment the three commented lines in ThisWorkbook. In short: the controls "react" to two things: 1. sheet change 2. button click.

@user23636411 1. SheetActivate means sheet activate (when you activate it), not sheet change. And second one means SheetProtect button - its OnAction event which has been hooked into mySheetProtect. In order to repurpose you should do something else when it is clicked. Making cancelDefault = False and sue the code to do whatever you need. In our case the event is hooked, used and then it is let to do what it usually does...
